# iOS Contact app style edit user information form

Tags: ios, uitableview, contacts

I want to create a page where user can edit their information like the iOS Contact App. However, from my understanding, the UITableView does not offer that option. It only allows you to insert cell, delete cell, rearrange cell (Am I correct?). **Is there an easy way to do this?**

I solution I can think of is to create a new cell for each user info, but it would be very tedious and messy because I will have to create custom cell for each user info type. If I have 5 cell type, then there'll be 15 additional files(.m .h .xib) for me to create. Or I can create the prototype cell in storyboard, but I don't know now to prevent it from reusing the cell and losing my data in the process.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for contact, you can try to use some of AddressBookUI framework built-in view, like the ABPersonViewController which allow to view and edit a contact.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1

Otherwise, if you need a custom form, there is not built-in iOS control to do this.

Interface Builder can help you using static cells (if you can support subclassing UITableViewController) or via prototype cell for each type of field (date, string, toggle, ...).

Also, You can check some github project which try to solve this:

- https://github.com/brunow/FormKit.m
- https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCTextFieldCell
- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=form

Hugues